# Git keeps loosing reference to stash

Tags: git, bitbucket, push

After cloning my repo from bitbucket I can push one commit.

But after that whenever I try to push I get the error (where things  brackets are the actual details not the placeholders used here):

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://<user>@<repo>/<path>/<name>.git'
```

I can clone the repo again, do one push again, but then get the same error.

Any help please?

Comment: What stash are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a pre-commit hook in my package.json that referenced a folder that no-longer existed.